# How can I parse a string to extract data using multiple user specified patterns in c#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, metadata

I have some users who want to parse a string and extract data. I don't know what the content of the string will be but the users know the pattern to each of their strings and would like to specify them using patterns.

E.g. The data we're working is metadata for audio files like album, artist, release date etc.

So each user may use separate string patterns to denote the format of their strings:

```
User 1: USER1-%album%-%releasedate%-DIRECTORY.mp3
User 2: %artist%_DIRECTORY_%genre%.aac
```

I need to use the above patterns (as an example, the actually pattern can vary for each user) to extract the metadata from the string.
So if the string is:

```
Bonjovi_Writer_rock.acc
```

I would need to extract the metadata by testing against pattern 1 which would not match and then match against pattern 2 and the artist would be bonjovi, genre would be rock and so on and so forth.

So to restate:

- I have an unknown string
- I have a pattern specified by a user

Is there a simple way in c# to extract the metadata from the string using the patterns and meta place holders specified in the pattern to match against the string?

Comment: What code have you written so far, that will allow us to help you much more.

Comment: You need some code which transforms a pattern into an algorithm to parse strings of that format. Not really going to be do able unless the accepted patterns are well defined. For example what do you do when I specify %%%%%FOO%%BAR%%BULLSHIT%% ? You could just make users specify regex patterns... That's kind of the idea of regex.

Comment: How does "DIRECTORY" match "Writer"?

Comment: This question is a little broad. You'll need to store the template the user selects in a database in way that you can retrieve it for that user, then use template to parse the string when necessary. There's not really any built in way to do this, if that's the question.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I think if you ask the user to specify regex...they will not.

Comment: @TimothyShields I don't necessarily disagree with that but if they can enter arbitrary patterns that have no strict definition then the problem cannot be solved. Another option would be to let them choose from a predetermined set of patterns or use a defined set of variable names and delimiting characters. None of them are very appealing.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal haha Yeah, I think we're in agreement then.

Comment: One thing that can make the parsing simpler is if you use "start" and "stop" characters for each replacement token. For example "<" and ">".  Then you can basically state to the user that they can't nest those. It makes the parsing much simpler: every "<" *must* be followed by a ">", with no other "<" or ">" in between.

Comment: I haven't written any code, yet, am looking for the best way to approach this.

Comment: Darn, sorry, hit enter prematurely. @evanmacdonnal there are no complex structure, just simple tags (no nested stuff).

Comment: @ShellShock, DIRECTORY is just some text it could be XYZ. Essentially how do I look for a pattern that matches the users inputs and extract the metatags.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is very broad, you not exactly get a solution - consider defining the pattern by which the users have to use in sending the feedback and use regex to extract that information. Hope this one helps